# How to bind plot function to x11() in R?

Tags: r, plot, x11

I have a function that has an infinite loop, and inside it plots `image` object, and I create an `x11()` window and plot it there, but when I close the window, the function keeps running in the background. My R code can be seen below:

```
plotInfinite <- function()
{
  while(TRUE)
  {
    mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 50*50, replace = TRUE), 50, 50)
    image(mat)
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
  }
}

x11()
plotInfinite()
```

Is it possible to somehow bind my function call to `x11()` window, such that when I close the window, also the function call terminates, i.e breaks from the infinite loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define it in function like

```
plotInfinite <- function()
{
  dev=dev.cur() # get cur device name
  tt=TRUE
  while(tt==TRUE)
  {

    mat <- matrix(sample(0:1, 50*50, replace = TRUE), 50, 50)
    image(mat)
    Sys.sleep(0.1)
    if(dev!=dev.cur()){ tt=FALSE} #check if device changed
  }
}
```

then

```
x11()
plotInfinite()
```

will work before closed